# Magento URL links Issue

Tags: magento

I am using this snippet in my CMS Static Blocks.

```
<li><a href="{{store url="contactus"}}">Contact Us</a></li>
```

I also tried `direct_url` and this one

```
<li><a href="{{store url=""}}contactus/">Contact Us</a></li>
```

But when I hover on the link on the page I see something like this

```
localhost/abc/index.php/{{store url="contactus"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get direct url in cms page, use below code.

```
{{store _direct="url-key-here"}}
```

Refer this [Link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14443/magento-get-store-url-in-cms-page)